# If I have 3 URLs using the same angular2 component, how can I detect the difference?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want /foo/add, /foo/id/1234, and /foo/modify/1234 to all use the same angular2 Component.

```
{path: '/foo/id/:id', name: 'FooView', component: FooComponent},
{path: '/foo/modify/:id', name: 'FooModify', component: FooComponent},
{path: '/foo/add', name: 'FooAdd', component: FooComponent},
```

In `FooComponent`, how can I tell which of the three states to use, View, Modify, or Edit? Is the best way just inject the `Router` and use `router.isRouteActive(router.generate(['FooView']))` for all 3 states?

Comment: personally felt question is bit confusing in last line of question..

Comment: @PankajParkar Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

Implement https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html which passes the next and previous instructions. This should allow to determine what path led to this component.

Another way would be to get the current instructions when https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7163 is shipped.

Currently you could also create a global service that subscribes route changes and would allow the component to get the current path.

```
@Injectable() 
export class RouterInfoService {
  currentRoute;
  constructor(private router:Router) {
    router.subscribe(value => { /* store route updates locally */ }
  }
}

@Component( ... )
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private routerInfoService:RouterInfoService) {}

  someFunc() {
    if(this.routerInfoService.currentRoute == ...) {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a singe route

```
{path: '/foo/:action/:id', name: 'Foo', component: FooComponent}
```

Then you can check for the `action` param alongside the `id` one.